# memory profiling in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i am running an exe from my C# code and i want to monitor the private bytes of the exe from my C# code...can anyone help?pls....

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread about profilers...[Any Decent C# Profilers out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. It has several properties for memory.