# .Net performance tool

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Does someone know which tool can I use to see which function in my .Net dll take so long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use either the Premium or Ultimate versions of Visual Studio, you'll have access to the built-in profiling tool via the "Analyze" main menu. See here for a step by step guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Other options are:

- [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler)
- [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler)
- [EQATEC Profiler](http://eqatec.com/tools/profiler)

I haven't used any of the above tools apart from the Visual Studio Profiler, but they may be worth trying out.

You may also wish to check out this thread, in addition to the one mentioned by Cory Larson: [Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there)

Answer (score 6):

RedGate's ANTS Profiler is great:

> http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Red Gates ANTs Profiler may be able to help.

Alternatively you could just use the [Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Comment: +1 for a heads-up on the stopwatch class!

Answer (score 2):

You could post it here for us to look at, or you might be interested in a .NET profiler. See the answers in this following SO post for ideas:

[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 2):

I had good experience with the [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/) profiler, it's free for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

The ANTS profiler is fantastic for this sort of thing: http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using RedGate's [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

We're using Dottrace profiler http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ It's sufficient for most of purposes. Actually you could use Ants, but my personal preference is for Dottrace