# find performance sensitive point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Can You suggest any software which can check my application while executing and show which methods take what time ?

thanks for help,
I need to solve performance issue and Im looking for bottlenecks

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a performance profiler. Check out Eqatec (free) or ANTS (not free). Both are solid. There are others, too; just Google performance profilers.

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of profilers listed here:

[Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually for starting out with performance analysis, VS 2010 doesn't do too bad of a job. Just select **Debug | Start Performance Analysis** and you can select what you are interested in, certainly it will show you the "hot spots" in your applications / in which functions the most time is spent in. The picture just shows a quick sample I took.

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, but it's worth noting that this is only available on the Premium or Ultimate editions of Visual Studio: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: good point Cody, there's also a free Ultimate edition trial for 30 days if you want to check out the features: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06a32b1c-80e9-41df-ba0c-79d56cb823f7