# How do I profile my C# application?

Tags: c#, profiling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
>   [Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there)

I've frequently wanted to profile code in our team's projects to compare speeds and efficiencies. However, according to Microsoft's [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx), the Visual Studio performance wizard isn't part of Visual Studio 2010 Professional, which is what we use.

Given this limitation, it seems a third-party application is required. I doubt I can convince my boss to spend much money on a profiling application. What options do I have, and how do I go about using such a tool?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the links to other questions regarding which profilers are available. Very useful! I'm editing this question to focus a little more about *how* to use these profilers. Are there any significant differences? In usability?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/10644 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3927 ? If users encounter performance problems your boss will be OK to spend a few 100$ to solve it.

Comment: A possible alternative to a third party application is upgrading to the Ultimate version of Visual Studio. You do have a subscription to MSDN, right?

Comment: @CharlesB: I suppose you don't know his bose :) Mine too, unfortunately...

Comment: I suspect downvotes because this question is somewhat a duplicate, which is [not what they're for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates/62824#62824).

Comment: @JYelton: Downvotes are meant to be used however the voter wants to use them. I've certainly downvoted duplicate questions that I think should have been found with even *minimal* effort on the part of the asker. But this one I downvoted because I don't think it's a good fit for a Q&A site. If it weren't a duplicate of a much better-asked question, I'd have voted to close it as "not constructive" or "not a real question" in addition to the downvote. You're essentially asking "What options do I have", which sounds a lot more like a poll than a question. It borders on subjective & argumentative.

Comment: @Cody: The question is "How do I profile" not "What options are there." It's unfortunate that I used that phrase in the question body, because it's misleading. I was hoping more for how profiling actually works because I've never used a profiler and was trying to find some basic beginner information. It would have been helpful, for example, to see an answer like, "You could use product X, it integrates into Visual Studio and you run it by selecting such and such from the menu." Or, "If you use product Y, you run it outside of VS on a compiled project like so..."

Comment: codetrack  free. portable  has flame chart. here:http://www.getcodetrack.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/)

Free, **performance only**, profiler. May be the best from all free profilers available in market today.

**EDIT**

From usability perspective EQATEC is pretty intuitive and simple to use, definitely recommend.

If, by the way, you are going to spend some money on it, the best I ever worked with till now, is  [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains: awesome one from both perspective (usability and performance). I'm talking about both of them Memory and Performance.

Regards.

Comment: Eqatec is no longer free and was bought out.

Comment: its been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

For free ones, I've found for a couple of times that free edition of [EQUATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Download.aspx) was quite usefull...

Comment: notice seconds mine and yours. Wow ! :)

Comment: for those who reaches all the way here...its been discontinued

Answer (score 0):

you might want to looks at this thread: [C# Profiler Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there)

I personally use ANTS Profiler and am very happy with it

Answer (score 0):

dotTrace Profiler is very nice and comes with 10day free trial.

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/buy/index.jsp)

Pricing doesn't look too bad either. $399 standard version.