# Optimizing the reaction-diffusion algorithm in Monogame C#

Tags: c#, optimization, visualization, simulation, monogame

I've implemented the reaction-diffusion algorithm following Karl Sims' tutorial. It is working fine but I'm only getting 10 fps on a 600x600 grid which seems excessively low and makes it unusable for my application.
How can I speed up my implementation or am I unintentionally misusing Monogames mechanisms?

This is my update-function, _a and _b are arrays containing the chemical concentrations.

```
    public void Update()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < N-1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < M-1; y++)
            {
                float a = _a[Index(x, y)];
                float b = _b[Index(x, y)];

                _bufferA[Index(x, y)] = a + DT * (DA * laplacian(x, y, _a) - a * b * b + Feed * (1 - a));
                _bufferB[Index(x, y)] = b + DT * (DB * laplacian(x, y, _b) + a * b * b - (Kill + Feed) * b);
            }
        }

        // Update the grid to the new values.
        (_a, _bufferA) = (_bufferA, _a);
        (_b, _bufferB) = (_bufferB, _b);
    }

    // Convolution that calculates the difference between chemical concentrations of neighbouring cells.
    private float laplacian(int x, int y, float[] arr)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                switch (Math.Abs(i) + Math.Abs(j))
                {
                    case 0: sum += -1 * arr[Index(x, y)]; break;
                    case 1: sum += 0.2f * arr[Index(x + i, y + j)]; break;
                    case 2: sum += 0.05f * arr[Index(x + i, y + j)]; break;
                }
        return sum;
    }
```

And this is how I draw it, I just pass a Texture2D to my class, modify it in there and draw it in the Game.Draw() function.

```
    public void Draw(Texture2D canvas)
    {
        Color[] data = new Color[Const.Width * Const.Height];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                data[i + j * N] = new Color((int)(255 * _a[Index(i, j)]), 0, (int)(255 * _b[Index(i, j)]));
            }
        }
        canvas.SetData(data);
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It could be really helpful, if you would add missing pieces, so I can put them into new MonoGame project easily. Currently it has a lot of missing definitions (`N`, `M`, `_a`, `_b`, `_bufferA`, `_bufferB`, `DT`, `DA`, `DB`, `Kill`, `Feed`, etc). I'm not an expert in this specific algorithm, but having running code I can check profiling results and try to optimize somethings keeping intact the logic.

Comment: One small improvement you might test is, in your Draw method, not to allocate a new Color[] data array every frame but reuse a single one (maybe even static) created at the start or when resizing the texture. This way, there should be less garbage collection, thus more FPS.

Comment: The `switch (Math.Abs(i) + Math.Abs(j))` statement inside `laplacian()` might be a little slow.  As a micro-optimization you might consider unfolding the two loops and eliminating the switch statement by doing the 9 `sum +=` statements manually.  But profile before you do.  See e.g. [How do I profile my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696241) to make sure it's actually worth the trouble.