# How can I do test for performance in C#

Tags: c#, testing, c#-4.0

How can I do test for performance in C#?

All that I know now is to use:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
{
     //code to test
}
sw.Stop();
```

Is there any other way to do this or is the above method wrong ?

Comment: As long as you calculate averages and don't require it to be super-accurate, it seems perfectly okay for me.

Comment: @ Maheep , i m nt using any tool.

Comment: @NIleshLanke I concur with whoever voted this as a duplicate of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers). The stopwatch is just going to tell you how much time something took, this is not performance. Profilers allow you to do all kind of things like memory consumption etc in addition to how long things took to run.

Comment: Have you tryed BenchmarkDotNet? it can test alot more then the time it takes a code to run, GC, Memory and such -> https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet 
Edit: Just notice the date on the topic ... sry

Answer (score 6):

`Stopwatch` is a good, simple way to measure the execution time of specific blocks of code. For  large-scale performance testing good tools are available, such as the ones listed in the following SO question:

- [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927/87698)

---

If you benchmark your code yourself (using `Stopwatch` or some other low-level tool), there are some things to watch out for:

- Run the test in an environment that most accurately resembles the target environment: Release build, no debugger attached, similar hardware.
- Keep in mind that the first run of a piece of code can have significantly different performance characteristics then subsequent runs (due to caching, JIT-ing, one-time initializers, etc.). If you are interested in the *average* execution time, do at least one "warmup" iteration first.

A few years ago, C# blogger Eric Lippert wrote a multi-part series on exactly that topic:

- [Fabulous adventure in coding: Benchmarking mistakes](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/)

Answer (score 2):

A better option to test the performance metrics in dotnet is [BenchMarkDotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html).

Example:

```
 public class Md5VsSha256
 {       

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] Sha256() => sha256.ComputeHash(data);

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] Md5() => md5.ComputeHash(data);
 }
```

Benchmark results

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sha256 | 100.90 us | 0.5070 us | 0.4494 us |
| Md5 | 37.66 us | 0.1290 us | 0.1207 us |

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can benefit from everything in [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx) namespace. Like `PerformanceCounter` class etc. `Stopwatch` being one of the alternatives you can use to measure time of execution.

If you have some money to spend you could use [RedGate Develper Bundle for .NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-developer-bundle/) 
It has Performance profiler, Memory profiler etc.

There also other cheaper [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there).