# WPF Application takes too long to start

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, fluent

I am creating a WPF Application that uses Fluent library.

On my computer with Windows 7, 2GB RAM and AMD Triple Core processor, after double clicking on the program icon, The Splash image shows after about 1-2 seconds.

But on my brother's old computer with Windows XP, 512MB RAM and Intel Celeron 2.0 GHz Processor (Single core), after double clicking on the program icon, First, a process called PresentationFontCache.exe runs and it uses almost 100% of CPU for some seconds. And Total time is needed for displaying the initial Splash image is almost 30 seconds (or more).

I don't want that some users have to wait 30 seconds for displaying splash image and about 7-8 seconds for loading application. (my application load process takes 7-8 seconds)

Also I think 1-2 seconds is too high for **just display initial SplashImage**, It should display immediately.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Performance issues can arise from many possible causes. You should provide more information such as performance tests you have run or the code that is being run.

Comment: It possible that VideoCard on your brother's PC much faster or your computer is a laptom with built-in videocard which has no own powerful CPU

Comment: @sll : Displaying a static PNG file needs as long as this?

Comment: Who know what is the real issue, perhaps it does not related to displaying PNG at all and problem is under the hood

Comment: R u including any Code Signing certificates?

Comment: @mhn : No, Also I don't know what is a Code Signing certificate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But on my brother's old computer with Windows XP, 512MB RAM and Intel Celeron 2.0 GHz Processor

Yeah, and guess waht - starting internet exlporer also takes a long time. This is not a computer, it is crap. At least 1gb memoery would help. WPF apps are not super low resorue aapps, they are made for modern OS.

> I don't want that some users have to wait 30 seconds for displaying splash image

Use the .NET standard flash mechanism (that loads even before the runtime is fully initialzied).

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/05/creating-splash-screen-without-code.html

THEN load the WPF code.

Comment: I have used the .NET standard flash mechanism and the splash screen shows **after 30 seconds**. Isn't there any way to at least show splash screen faster?

Comment: And another thing : Why that process "PresentationFontCache.exe" runs on my brother's computer but doesn't run on my computer when I trying to run my application?

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you could profile your application for performance to see where your bottleneck is and discover what is causing it so that you can know what to fix in your code to optimize performance.

You can use the classes [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx) namespace. Like PerformanceCounter class etc.

If you have some money to spend you could use [RedGate Develper Bundle for .NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-developer-bundle/) It has Performance profiler, Memory profiler etc.

There also other [cheaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there) alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Presentationfontcache.exe is a is a Windows Presentation Foundation Service from Microsoft Corporation belonging to .NET Framework. It normally uses high CPU.

You could try stopping the service, by deleting the file it creates: Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\FontCache4.0.0.0.dat and restarting the service to check if that helps.

Comment: Why that process runs when I want to run my application??