# is there any sort of tool that will return response times for each method called in an operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stack-trace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
>   [Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there)

I'm doing some speed optimization and was wondering if there's any sort of tool available that will return the time it takes for each method/behavior called in that operation chain to complete. So like if the method LoadLists(); starts a chain of methods to build and load those lists, I'd like to see a report of something like:

```
LoadLists Total Process Time: 10s
FindDirectReports: 1s
FindManager: .035s
FindGroups: 1s
LoadPhotos: 5.234s
```

and so on...

Anyone know of anything?

Comment: yes, this is what a profiler is for ;)

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there).

Comment: I miss the old Borland profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate do Ants profiler which is excellent.
Jetbrains do DotTrace which is good, but in my personal opinion not quite as good as Ants. Ants is more expensive though.

Visual Studio Ultimate has some performance tools built in. I had mixed results using those.

As far as I know there are no free solutions which profile apps, especially web apps.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all VS SKUs come with the profiler.

Comment: There is the MVC Mini Profiler, but of course it only works with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You could spend hours adding some profiling code using Stopwatch, but I would recommend using Redgate Ants, it is possible to get a free triel.