# debug memory usage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

One of our ASP.NET MVC3 web app takes too much memory while hosted on single IIS7 pool. Sometimes up to 1gb.  Where I should start and how to find memory issues, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the database first, as that will be mostly the case to step up your memory allocation.

- Are you closing all open connections?
- Are you reusing the open connection to get more data from the database?
- Are you open and close the connection for each call?

There are several tools out there that provide you with Profiling, both code and memory, but before jumping out into one of them, try "our" own **StackOverflow Profiling** now called [Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to help you realize where are you wasting more time, how long your queries take and see if you're doing the database access correctly...

If that does not help, try one of the free/commercial tools out there like:

- [.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)
- [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/)
- [dotTrace 4 Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
- [EQATEC Profiler](http://eqatec.com/profiler/)

or follow up this question

> [Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there)