# IIS website gradually gets slower until restarted

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, windows-server, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 website on IIS8 on windows server 2012.

When the website is first started it is quite fast, but it gradually gets slower throughout the day. If I restart IIS the problem is fixed and it is fast again but then the cycle continues and it gets slower.

Where can I start on trying to diagnose this problem..?

Comment: It sounds like your application code is leaking objects or has a thread stuck in a loop somewhere. Have you audited your code and are you using `using(){}` and `IDisposable` correctly?

Comment: Use some profiler to find your leak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there

Comment: Check which page is consuming most memory. You can get some information from worker process present in IIS